# Triangle/Slanted Menu Style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I would like to create the following webpage, where the navigation bar drops down on and is slanted.
So when a user opens the website its front page looks like
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyU1H.jpg)

Then when a user presses the "menu button" (which I have not drawn), the following menu bar appears (ideally slides down as an animation)
[image]

I really need help with designing the slanted navigation bar and adding the subsequent animation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an SVG shape as a background, and really any shape you want to make.

[CodePen Link with an animation as well](https://codepen.io/ryanjmcgowan/pen/gOPWBzG)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="triangle-container">
      <svg height="300" width="500">
            <polygon points="0,-200 500,-200 500,100" class="triangle" />
            Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
      </svg>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
}

.triangle-container{
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  
    &:hover, &:active{
      .triangle{
        transform: translate(0px, 200px);
      }
    }
  
  .triangle{
    fill: black;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  
  @keyframes mymove {
    0%   {opacity:0}
    50%  {opacity:1}
    100% {opacity:0}
  }
    
    transform-origin: 250px 250px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is if you have a triangle image, with a height of 0. And all of your menu items are off the top of the screen, out of view. When you want the menu to slide down, use jquery animate to increase image height and slide all of the menu items down.

```
const time = 700;

$("#triangleId").animate({
    height: "+=10px"
}, time);
$("#menuItemOneId, #menuItemTwoId...").animate({
    top: "+=10px"
}, time);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a little way using clip-path and css keyframes. This way you can avoid javascript and the code is responsive no pixels needed.

**HTML**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class = 'navbar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```css
.navbar{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 25vh;
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%,0% 0%);
  animation: open 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes open{
  0% {clip-path:polygon(100% 0, 100% 0,100% 0);}
  100% {clip-path:polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%,0% 0%);}
}
```

Link to code pen for this:
https://codepen.io/mfortunato/pen/jOWmXvL